# jquery, a load() inside a before()

Tags: jquery, load

Is it possible to execute a load function inside a before function ?
I'm trying

```
$('#test').before(load('test.html'));
```

but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

You can do that if `.before()` has any callback but it doesn't have any callback so you can't do that. instead use `$.ajax` and append response before your desired `DOM`.

OR See Example below.

```
$('#test').load('test.html', data, function(response)
{ 
    $(this).before(response);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i didn't quite understand what response is ?!?

Comment: @GradislavaBikkulova , response is the result values or html of test.html page...

Comment: oh ok, it's working but it also replaces $('#test') by test.html, so I don't have $('#test') anymore but test.html two times

Comment: @GradislavaBikkulova paste html so i can help better

Comment: oh ok, thanks i must have did a silly thing, thanks again for everything

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't work like that.

Instead, you need to manually send an AJAX request to get the content, then call `before()` when it arrives to insert it into the DOM.

Comment: you mean $('#test').load('test.html').before() ??